# FREETEXTTABLE always returns same ranks for all records

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

Below query always returns the same RANK for all records. I've tried not to use quotes and result is the same. Also I've tried to delete\create new index without luck.

```
select * from FREETEXTTABLE(tProductCharItem, pci_name, '"Размер"') t
            join tProductCharItem pci on t.[KEY] = pci.pci_id
            order by [rank] desc
```

| KEY | RANK | pci_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 53 | 80 | Размер |
| 89 | 80 | Размер люльки (ШxД), см |
| 90 | 80 | Размер прогулочного блока (ШxД), см |
| 91 | 80 | Размер спального места, см |
| 154 | 80 | Размер матраса |
| 209 | 80 | Размер пеленального столика (ШхД), см |

Sample data:

```
create table tProductCharItem(pci_id int identity(1,1) primary key, pci_name nvarchar(100))
insert into tProductCharItem(pci_name) select 'Размер'
insert into tProductCharItem(pci_name) select 'Размер люльки (ШxД), см'
insert into tProductCharItem(pci_name) select 'Размер прогулочного блока (ШxД), см'
insert into tProductCharItem(pci_name) select 'Размер спального места, см'
insert into tProductCharItem(pci_name) select 'Размер матраса'
insert into tProductCharItem(pci_name) select 'Размер пеленального столика (ШхД), см'
insert into tProductCharItem(pci_name) select 'Размер спального места подростковой кровати'
insert into tProductCharItem(pci_name) select 'Размер подножки, см'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your database. E.g. as a few lines of "create table ...." and "insert ...". The provided table view lacks info and is inconvenient to use for reproducing.

Comment: I don't know if Microsoft reveals much about how their FREETEXTABLE rank algorithm works, it appears an exact match ranks the same if the word is at the beginning of the field. I think if your search word was later in the text string (not at the beginning), it would have a difference value. So if you had one field where it was "blah blah Размер", then it would have lower rank. If you need exact matches to rank higher, maybe just add a CASE WHEN col = "SearchParam" and have use it to rank your data before you look at the FREETEXTTABLE rank